# IDL interpol equivalent for python

Tags: python-2.7, idl-programming-language

What would be a python equivalent for the INTERPOL function as seen in the following IDL code:

```
x  = interpol(a,b,c)
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

In your notation, the IDL interp function uses **a** as the input values, **b** as input abscissa values and **c** is the desired abscissa values you want to interpolate onto.

In python (for 1D) it would be [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

```
from scipy import interpolate
interpfunc = interpolate.interp1d(b,a, kind='linear')
x=interpfuc(c)
```

scipy includes many more interpolation functions, including interp2d and griddata that you may find useful:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html